# Laurent series of $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-4)(z-1)}$ on $1<\vert z \vert <4$. And $\int f dz$.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I need to find the Laurent series expansion of

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-4)(z-1)}$$

about $1<\vert  z \vert <4.$

So after partial fraction decomp I get

$$\frac{1}{(z-4)(z-1)}=\frac{1}{3}\bigg(\frac{1}{z-4}-\frac{1}{z-1} \bigg).$$

And I can rewrite this as

$$\frac{1}{3}\bigg(-\frac{1}{4}\bigg( \frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{4}}\bigg) +\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{z}}\bigg)$$

So I get

$$\frac{1}{3}\bigg(-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{z^n}{4^{n+1}})+\sum_{n=-1}^{-\infty}z^n\bigg).$$

Did I do this last step correctly? And for the integral I get $\frac{2\pi i}{3}$. Domain of integral is circle center at $4$ of radius $1$.

Comment: Can you specify the integration domain? The series looks right.

Comment: What integral? You have only mentioned an indefinite integral in your title.

Comment: Also - depending on where you're integrating, you can express your result as a Cauchy-type integral (or even use residues).

Comment: @YanZhu circle center $4$, radius $1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson circle center $4$, radius $1$.

Comment: @YanZhu so is my $-1$ term $1/3$?

Comment: Without using the Laurent series, it's easy to calculate the residue of $f$ at the pole at $z=4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your solution is correct.

Last step $$\frac{1}{3}\bigg(-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{z^n}{4^{n+1}})+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^n}\bigg).$$
here the co-effient of $\frac{1}{z}$ is $\frac{1}{3}$.

Using **Residue theorem** the value of integral is:
$2\pi i$ $\times$ (co-efficient of $\frac{1}{z}$)

which is $\frac{2\pi i}{3}$.

Comment: hey , I tried doing this again and I fail to see why the second series is positive when if we divide by z we get 1-1/z already so our sign stays negative, right? or